Webhook Datastructure at Make.com for Flowise to Discord prompt triggered messages
I'm currently trying to create a Chatflow in Flowise where the user can speak to a LLM and be able to ask it to send a message to Discord by connecting the two via Webhook in a Make.com Scenario.
I followed the Guide in the Flowise documentation and I have a Webhook linking Discord to Make and then another one linking Make and Flowise.
At the moment while the LLM tells me that it succesfully sent the message to discord when I request it, nothing arrives on the Discordchannel.
When I start the Scenario in Make manually it says that the Webhook linking to Flowise is not able to generate a bundle.
Is it a problem in how I have to set up the Data Structure in the Make to Flowise Webhook so the Discord one can properly recognize the Message?
If so what do I need to change?
These are my current settings:

Webhook to Flowise

Data Structure in Webhook to Flowise

Webhook to Discord


The JS in my Flowise custom tool is as follows:

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const webhookUrl = 'https://hook.eu2.make.com/redacted';
const body = {
    "message": $message
};
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
try {
    const response = await fetch(webhookUrl, options);
    const text = await response.text();
    return text;
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return '';
}


Apparently something was wrong with the link in the settings in the Discord module on Make.com.
Re-inserting the link the Discord client gave me when I set up the bot there into the Make.com module fixed the issue and also made some of the other settings I had tried out obsolete (none other the ones mentioned in the Make.com docs were needed).
